have a list of week numbers, how can I find the days corresponding to it python
I have a list of weeks for 2024: wks = [2,3,4,5,6,7...18]
How can I extract the dates that correspond to each week, bearing in mind, that the week starts on a Tuesday?
As Jan 1, 2024 was Monday, I have no data
Jan 2, 2024 was Tuesday, and data starts generating, hence why I have no wk 1
Here, I would like wk_starting = ['Jan 2, 2024', 'Jan 9, 2024,....,'Feb 7, 2024'....,'Apr 23, 2024'] and wk_composed_of = ['Jan 2 - 8', 'Jan 9 - 16',...,'Feb 7-16'....,'Apr 23-29']

What have you tried so far?

I refer you to the datetime module

thanks, datetime module helped


# Define the start date
start_date = datetime(2024, 1, 2)  # Jan 2, 2024

# Define the end date
end_date = datetime(2024, 12, 31)  # Dec 31, 2024

# Generate list of dates from start to end date
date_range = [start_date + timedelta(days=x) for x in range((end_date - start_date).days + 1)]

# Divide the list into lists of 7 days each
weeks = [date_range[i:i + 7] for i in range(0, len(date_range), 7)]

# Format the dates in the desired format
formatted_weeks = [[date.strftime('%b %d, %Y') for date in week] for week in weeks]

# Print the result
for i, week in enumerate(formatted_weeks, start=1):
    print(f"Week {i}: {week}")```

it is in the format of list of list of 7 days so you can search by week and by day.

output:


Week 1: ['Jan 02, 2024', 'Jan 03, 2024', 'Jan 04, 2024', 'Jan 05, 2024', 'Jan 06, 2024', 'Jan 07, 2024', 'Jan 08, 2024']
Week 2: ['Jan 09, 2024', 'Jan 10, 2024', 'Jan 11, 2024', 'Jan 12, 2024', 'Jan 13, 2024', 'Jan 14, 2024', 'Jan 15, 2024']
Week 3: ['Jan 16, 2024', 'Jan 17, 2024', 'Jan 18, 2024', 'Jan 19, 2024', 'Jan 20, 2024', 'Jan 21, 2024', 'Jan 22, 2024']
Week 4: ['Jan 23, 2024', 'Jan 24, 2024', 'Jan 25, 2024', 'Jan 26, 2024', 'Jan 27, 2024', 'Jan 28, 2024', 'Jan 29, 2024']
Week 5: ['Jan 30, 2024', 'Jan 31, 2024', 'Feb 01, 2024', 'Feb 02, 2024', 'Feb 03, 2024', 'Feb 04, 2024', 'Feb 05, 2024']
Week 6: ['Feb 06, 2024', 'Feb 07, 2024', 'Feb 08, 2024', 'Feb 09, 2024', 'Feb 10, 2024', 'Feb 11, 2024', 'Feb 12, 2024']
Week 7: ['Feb 13, 2024', 'Feb 14, 2024', 'Feb 15, 2024', 'Feb 16, 2024', 'Feb 17, 2024', 'Feb 18, 2024', 'Feb 19, 2024']
Week 8: ['Feb 20, 2024', 'Feb 21, 2024', 'Feb 22, 2024', 'Feb 23, 2024', 'Feb 24, 2024', 'Feb 25, 2024', 'Feb 26, 2024']
Week 9: ['Feb 27, 2024', 'Feb 28, 2024', 'Feb 29, 2024', 'Mar 01, 2024', 'Mar 02, 2024', 'Mar 03, 2024', 'Mar 04, 2024']

